# Cannot add/edit external links on Wordpress - receive 404 Requested URL cannot be found

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm working on my Wordpress production site and I'm having a strange error that doesn't allow me to add or edit any Link which points to an external URL (not on my domain). Originally I could do that, as I managed to submit many links for my site before that.

Going through the Links menu I can open any of the existing Links, but when I press the Update button, a blank page with the 404 error page appears. If I do the same with a link on my domain, it works perfectly! 
I have researched on this subject but could not find anything similar. I'm really frustrated.

Any help is much appreciated!

My environment:

- Working with WP 3.5.1, PHP 5.3.6
- Using Permalinks custom: /%postname%
- Windows 2012 Server with IIS 8 and URL rewrite (no .htaccess)

Rules I'm using:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```